# Need help with a complex MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to get a final result set for a 3 table hierarchical set of data. Hopefully, the diagrams will indicate what I have and what I'm trying to do. Briefly, my final result set (below) should easily allow me to define a dynamic number of checkboxes in my web site, while also allowing me to define whether the boxes are checked, all from within a single result set.  I believe that since the data is normalized, I should be able to get a single result set, but I can't get my head wrapped around this on...   Can anyone help??

```
    TABLE A                    TABLE B                 TABLE C       
    MEMBER                     CONTACT                 ALERT     
(pk)$member_id  ->         (pk)$contact_id  ->       (pk)$alert_id     
                           (fk)$member_id            (fk)$contact_id    
                                                         $alert_type ->   
                                                             -> 'local', 'state', 'nation'
```

Example of my filter criteria is member_id = 1 AND alert_type = 'local'

```
* = results of filter member_id = 1

TABLE MEMBERS A
+----------+----------+
|member_id |   Name   |
+----------+----------+
|     1    |   Alan   | *
|     2    |   Brad   |
|     3    |   Doug   |
|     4    |   Flo    |
+---------------------+

TABLE CONTACTS B 
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| contact_id |  member_id  |    email      |    phone     |   Name   |
+------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+----------+
|     1      |     1       |  a@gmail.com  |              |   Alex   | *
|     2      |     1       |  b@gmail.com  | 123-456-7890 |   Bob    | *
|     3      |     3       |  c@gmail.com  |              |   Cris   |
|     4      |     1       |  d@gmail.com  |              |   Dan    | *
|     5      |     2       |  e@gmail.com  |              |   Ed     |
|     6      |     1       |  f@gmail.com  |              |   Fran   | *
|     7      |     1       |  g@gmail.com  | 212-323-1111 |   Greg   | *
|     8      |     2       |  h@gmail.com  |              |   Hans   |
|     9      |     3       |  i@gmail.com  |              |   Ida    |
|    10      |     1       |  j@gmail.com  | 945-555-1212 |   Jeff   | *
|    11      |     2       |  k@gmail.com  | 945-555-1212 |   Karl   |
|    12      |     3       |  l@gmail.com  |              |   Leo    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+

# = resutls of filter alert_type = 'local'
TABLE CONTACTS_SELECTED C
+-----------------------------------------+         
|  alert_id  | contact_id |  alert_type   |
+------------+------------+---------------+         
|     1      |     1      |     local     | * #
|     2      |     1      |     state     | *
|     3      |     3      |     state     |
|     4      |     5      |     local     |
|     5      |     5      |     state     |
|     6      |     6      |     nation    | *
|     7      |     7      |     local     | * #
|     8      |     8      |     nation    |  
|     9      |    10      |     local     | *
|    10      |    12      |     state     |
+-------------------------+---------------+
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|member_id | contract_id  |    email      |    phone     |   Name   |   alert_type   |
+----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
|     1    |      1       |  a@gmail.com  |              |   Alex   |    local       |
|     1    |      2       |  b@gmail.com  | 123-456-7890 |   Bob    |     NULL       |
|     1    |      4       |  d@gmail.com  |              |   Dan    |     NULL       |
|     1    |      6       |  f@gmail.com  |              |   Fran   |    nation      |
|     1    |      7       |  g@gmail.com  | 212-323-1111 |   Greg   |    local       |
|     1    |     10       |  j@gmail.com  | 945-555-1212 |   Jeff   |    local       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

With this result set, I should be easily able to FOREACH my way through all 6 records and create a checkbox for each record, and flag those records with 'local' as checked. Can anyone help with setting up this complex query?  

--
-- Table structure for table `contacts`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `contact_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `contacts`
--

INSERT INTO `contacts` (`contact_id`, `member_id`, `email`, `phone`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'a@gmail.com', '', 'Alex'),
(2, 1, 'b@gmail.com', '123-456-7890', 'Bob'),
(3, 3, 'c@gmail.com', '', 'Cris'),
(4, 1, 'd@gmail.com', '987-654-3210', 'Dan'),
(5, 2, 'e@gmail.com', '', 'Ed'),
(6, 1, 'f@gmail.com', '', 'Fran'),
(7, 2, 'h@gmail.com', '234-567-8901', 'Hans'),
(8, 3, 'i@gmail.com', '', 'Ida'),
(9, 1, 'g@gmail.com', '', 'Greg'),
(10, 1, 'j@gmail.com', '456-789-0123', 'Jeff'),
(11, 2, 'k@gmail.com', '945-555-1212 ', 'Karl'),
(12, 3, 'l@gmail.com', '', 'Leo');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts_selected` (
  `alert_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `alert_type` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`alert_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `contacts_selected`
--

INSERT INTO `contacts_selected` (`alert_id`, `contact_id`, `alert_type`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'local'),
(2, 1, 'state'),
(3, 3, 'state'),
(4, 5, 'local'),
(5, 5, 'state'),
(6, 6, 'nation'),
(7, 7, 'local'),
(8, 8, 'nation'),
(9, 10, 'local'),
(10, 12, 'state'),
(11, 1, 'nation');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `alert_types` (
  `alert_type` varchar(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `alert_types`
--

INSERT INTO `alert_types` (`alert_type`) VALUES
('local'),
('state'),
('nation');


SOLUTION:
$alert_type = 'local';
// choices are local, state, nation
//
SELECT c.contact_id, c.member_id, c.email, c.phone, c.desc, s.alert_type 
FROM contact c
    LEFT JOIN contact_select s 
    ON c.contact_id = s.contact_id
WHERE c.member_id = 1 AND c.contact_id NOT IN
(SELECT cs.contact_id FROM contact_select cs WHERE cs.alert_type = '$alert_type')
GROUP BY c.contact_id 
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT c.contact_id, c.member_id, c.email, c.phone, c.desc, s.alert_type 
    FROM contact c
    LEFT JOIN contact_select s 
    ON c.contact_id = s.contact_id
    WHERE c.member_id = 1 
    AND s.contact_id 
    IN (SELECT cs.contact_id FROM contact_select cs WHERE cs.alert_type = '$alert_type')) z
WHERE z.alert_type = '$alert_type'
```

Comment: Also, in what way is this hierarchical? You're not talking about a recursive hierarchy, I assume. You just mean master/detail, correct?

Comment: What have you tried?  The `alert_type` can be multiple values -- how do you know the first to be "local" in your required output

Comment: @Jordan - yes, a one-to-many and not recursive if I understand the concept of recursive.  My concern is that I have indeed violated one of the more obscure normal forms (4th) in that alert_types are not broken out in into another table somehow.

OMG - not sure what you're asking, but see the post below and I will further explain what I am getting when trying their sample query.

Comment: You mention a website to enter criteria... will a person ever have a chance to enter more than one type( ie: Local, State, Nation )?  If so, do you want the first one that qualifies the criteria (such as any Local, but the contact has both local, state AND/OR nation available) ?

Comment: @DRapp, yes but...   Each page filters for a separate alert_type and users decide on which alerts they want to recieve on each subsequent page (ie local, state or nation).  The same contacts will appear on each web page (member_id = 1), but the checked status varies from page to page (alert_type = local, state or nation).  Make sense?  That's why I want this particular result set. I do have a new normalized model posted in the area above...  Filtering from the top down in my hierarchy, as opposed to bottom up, should give me the proper result set.  Just need to create the complex select now.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I changed the data model to what I think is BCNF (Boyce-Codd Normal Form) adding another parent table above contacts_selected - this is where one would do the filter for alert_type = 'local'.  So I am back to a 3 table query, with two parent tables (contacts and alert_types) and a common child table (contacts_selected) (see above).

Answer (score 0):

```
select member_id, cs.contract_id, c.email, c.phone, c.name, cs.alert_type 
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN contact_selected cs on cs.contact_id = c.contact_id
WHERE c.member_id = 1
```

Not sure i understand well what do you mean but maybe you're looking for thiS?

Comment: Thanks very kindly for the help.  Unfortunately, I already tried this query and it didn't work. Any records in Table C for the chosen member_id (=1) with more than one contact_id entry will not yield a distinct row value, but rather will be displayed as many times as there are records with that contact_id. (sample data attached)

Comment: My query result (if possible to do this) should contain ONLY 6 rows. Any of these rows (contacts) which also have an alert_type of 'local' for example if that is the filter criteria, should be indicated on the row for that contact.  If that contact does not possess a record with the value 'local', it can either display NULL, 'nation' or 'state' - I don't care...
Is is possible I have, in fact, violated some other normal form  (ie 4th) in my use of how I store the alert_types?  I always got confused by the time I reached that stage of normalization. I'll go back and read it AGAIN!!!   Ugh...

Answer (score 0):

This should give you your desired output.

```
SELECT C.member_id, C.contact_id, C.email, C.phone, C.name, S.alert_type 
FROM CONTACTS C 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTACTS_SELECTED S
        ON C.contact_id = S.contact_id 
WHERE member_id = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, some of the contact records are duplicated.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
select `c`.`contact_id`, `member_id`, `email`, `phone`, `name`, `alert_type` from contacts `c`
left join contacts_selected `s` on `c`.`contact_id` = `s`.`contact_id`
where member_id=1
group by `c`.`contact_id`
```

However, two points: One, it's not clear to me how you want to narrow the result set to select only one of the alert types. Two, your sample data and your insert statments contain slightly different data. That's not a problem, but it is a little confusing at first.

Comment: This does finally appear to be what I needed.  OMG!!  Thank you so much.  I completely forgot about the Group by clause!!   DUH!!  I haven't had a reason for almost 7 years to dabble in SQL and thought I had a handle on it still...  Lesson learned.

I did expand the sample data a bit after I put in the original tables.  Sorry if that ate up any of your time dealing with it.  I tried my best to make this easy to conceptualize.  The inserts were added today - visual sample data was done yesterday.  

Anyone reading this, please ignore the BCNF additions - they were a dead end. thx all!  SOLVED